# Disable the sort arrow in a specific column in QTableWidget with PyQt/PySide

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtablewidget

[image][image]

I would like to remove the arrow from the first column heading so the title is centered with the checkboxes. All of this without disabling the possibility to sort the column.

This is my current code.

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QProxyStyle,
    QStyle,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
)


class ProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def subElementRect(self, e, opt, widget):
        r = super().subElementRect(e, opt, widget)
        if e == QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator:
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
        return r


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, 3, 1)
        self._style = ProxyStyle(self.style())
        self.setStyle(self._style)
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                it = QTableWidgetItem()
                self.setItem(i, j, it)
                it.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                it.setCheckState(Qt.Checked if (i + j) % 2 == 0 else Qt.Unchecked)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Table()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to override the [`drawControl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawControl) and set the `indicator` of the QStyleOptionHeader to 0 if the column matches the one you want to hide.

```
class ProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    # ...
    def drawControl(self, ctl, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if ctl == QStyle.CE_HeaderSection and opt.orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            if opt.section == widget.parent().property('hideSortIndicatorColumn'):
                opt.sortIndicator = 0
        super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.setProperty('hideSortIndicatorColumn', 0)
```

Be aware that setting the style on a widget is not always enough for complex widgets that have children.
In your case it works because you added the current style to the proxy constructor, but this means that the ownership of the style will be *completely* taken by the proxy, and any other QWidget will use the proxy from that moment on (which is almost the same as setting the proxy to the whole application).
The alternative is to create the proxy without any argument (in this case a *new instance* of the default native style will be used), but that also means that **no** children of the widget will inherit the style, since QStyles are not propagated to their children.

Comment: It works perfectly with PyQt5, but I have `AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QStyleOption' object has no attribute 'section'` and `AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QStyleOption' object has no attribute 'orientation'` with PySide.

Comment: Mh. I know some changes are being made during the current transition to Qt6 (which is a good reason to avoid it right now if you really don't need it). Did you use *exactly* my code? Just to be safe, you can ensure that the `opt` is a `QStyleOptionHeader` type. `opt.rect` and `opt.direction` are *not* what I'm using: `opt.rect` is the rectangle in which the painting happens, and `direction` is the *writing direction* (used for right-to-left languages), and the properties are the same for PySide too (including PySide6): https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QStyleOptionHeader.html

Comment: It only works with PyQt5, opt is always `QStyleOption` with PySide2 and PySide6.

Comment: @0lan I cannot use PySide right now, what if you try to create a new option with the current one? `newopt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionHeader(opt)` then use that `newopt` for the rest of the function.